# UWP rotation button animation

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to reproduce an animation for a button, like the animation of the native camera app buttons of Windows 10 Mobile, but I'm lost.

I'm using this example as a basis:
[CameraStarterKit](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit)

The rotation of the buttons is already ok. o que eu gostaria de implementar era a animação.

Here is the code that the rotate buttons:

```
    private void UpdateButtonOrientation()
    {
        int device = ConvertDeviceOrientationToDegress(_deviceOrientation);
        int display = ConvertDisplayOrientationToDegrees(_displayOrientation);

        if (_displayInformation.NativeOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Portrait)
        {
            device -= 90;
        }

        var angle = (360 + display + device) % 360;

        var transform = new RotateTransform { Angle = angle };

        PhotoButton.RenderTransform = transform;
    }
```

How do I include an animation in this code.

Already grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `RotateTransform` property to your **Button**

```
<Button Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="PhotoButton"
        Content="PhotoButton"
        Click="PhotoButton_Click"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="PhotoButtonRotateTransform"/>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

After that, you can create and manage `Storyboard` in code like this:

```
private void PhotoButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AnimateProgressRingSlice(PhotoButtonRotateTransform.Angle + 90);
}

private void AnimateProgressRingSlice(double to, double miliseconds = 350)
{
    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(miliseconds);
    doubleAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
    doubleAnimation.To = to;
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "Angle");
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, PhotoButtonRotateTransform);
    storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

**Remark**

But be careful if you don't know about `RenderTransformOrigin` property. Read [More Info](http://www.dotnetperls.com/rendertransform)

I guess you need to use this property with `0.5, 0.5` value, so, modify your `XAML` and add to `Button`

```
RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5
```

Look the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define the animation as a Storyboard in the resources of your page:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <Storyboard x:Name="rotate90">
      ... some animation that changes the RenderTransform of the button
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PhotoButtonRotateTransform"
           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
           Value="90" x:Name="RotationAnimation" />
   </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

And then start the animation from your code-behind:

```
private void UpdateButtonOrientation()
{
    //here you can put some logic that 
    //sets the target value for the RotationAnimation's Value property    
    rotateButtonStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

For more information about animations and Storyboards check out the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/storyboarded-animations)